# How to get Django 1.5 login_required decorator to return 403 status code

Tags: python, django, django-1.5

There is no raise_exception parameter that seems to work.

```
@login_required
def hi (request):
  return HttpResponse("hello")
```

I need to call this from AJAX javascript so I do not want a redirect, just a 403 status code is good.

Answer (score 4):

Just put the check in the view itself...

```
def hi(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
      # Allow access.
    else:
        raise MyException()
```

...or use your own decorator that applies similar logic.

Edit:  Sample decorator added.

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponseForbidden
from django.utils.decorators import available_attrs
from functools import wraps

def alt_login_required(function=None):
    def decorator(view_func):
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.user.is_authenticated():
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponseForbidden()

        return wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))(_wrapped_view)
    if function is None:
        return decorator
    else:
        return decorator(function)
```

Comment: thanks/+1 but i do not want to replicate the if-else for every view

Comment: Write a custom decorator.

Comment: i tried the sample decorator but i get: `global name 'wraps' is not defined`

Comment: I have included the import statements required.

Comment: As an alternative, you could use the [`permission_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.permission_required) decorator, which accepts an argument `raise_exception` to tell it to raise a 403 instead of redirect - just check against a permission that all your users will have.